# Show that for QM operator $A$ that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi A^{\dagger}A\psi dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(A\psi)^*(A\psi)dx $

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

I need to show for $$A = \frac{d}{dx} + \tanh x, \qquad A^{\dagger} = - \frac{d}{dx} + \tanh x,$$  that

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^* A^{\dagger}A\psi dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(A\psi)^*(A\psi)dx. $$

Where $\psi$ is a normalized wavefunction. I thought that this was the definition of the Hermitian conjugate of an operator $A$, but the problem asks for me to use integration by parts. I don't really see where the result is going to come from here, surely it is not messy calculation, since it is true in general, right?

I started by by integrating by parts, noting that the surface terms must vanish since $\psi$ is normalized, but after that I just get into a big mess...

Comment: This isn't homework, so I removed the tag.

Comment: The homework tag isn't only for actual homework problems. It's for all questions that are homework-like. (read the tag description for more info) The tag is appropriate here.

Comment: Ok, I'll put it back then.

Comment: Hi Hayeder. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: I did, apologies for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

Your set-up isn't quite right.

a) the relationship should be \begin{equation}\int^\infty_{-\infty} \psi^*A^\dagger A \psi dx = \int^\infty_{-\infty} (A\psi)^*( A\psi) dx \end{equation}

b)
The Hermitian conjugate of $\frac{d}{dx}$ is $-\frac{d}{dx}$, so the operator is not Hermitian. For that, you need $A= -i\frac{d}{dx}$ (so the Hermitian conjugate is $A^\dagger = i\frac{d}{dx}$).

Hopefully, that will help.

Comment: Set $D = \frac{d}{dx}$.  Integration by parts gives $\langle f, D g \rangle = fg|_{-\infty}^\infty - \langle D f, g\rangle$.  So $D^\dagger = -D$.

Comment: Thank you for noticing the error, but $\frac{d}{dx}$ is anti-hermitian

Comment: Yes.  That's what I said.  No need for 'but'.

Comment: haha, I wasn't talking to you, sorry. I was just letting James know the correct format of the question, rather than speaking on whether or not $\frac{d}{dx}$ is Hermitian.

Comment: Sorry, made a complete hash of that (the lessons of not posting answers just before you go to bed).

Comment: Shouldn't there be a minus before one of $\frac d{dx}$ in "The Hermitian conjugate of $\frac d{dx}$ is $\frac d{dx}$"?